# Chart legend entry width

Tags: excel, vba, legend-properties, excel-charts

How do I get the correct width of each legend entry in a chart? I have used the width property of the LegendEntry but this doesn't give the correct value.

For example, using the below legend:

[image]

if I check each legend entry's width using `LegendEntry.Width` I get the same width for each entry

A = 67, word = 67, Longer sentence = 67,

Which is obviously incorrect, it's probably assigned the longest width to all entries. So how do i get the actual width of each entry?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the chart's legend entry is automatically resized according to the number of letters.

So it is an anomaly, but it seems to be necessary to adjust the number of characters to be blank. It is **not** an **exact match**, but space * 2 seems **similar**.

```
Sub setCharts(Target As Range, Cht As Chart)
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim vColor, vName
    Dim i As Integer, Ln As Integer, k As Integer

    vColor = Array(RGB(246, 246, 246), RGB(255, 224, 140), RGB(47, 157, 39), RGB(0, 0, 0))
    vName = Array("A", "Word", "Longer sentence", "stack")

    Ln = Len(vName(2)) '<~~~ "Longer sentence" 's length  --> Collection name

    '******  The Loop statement below makes the series names the same length ******

'    For i = 0 To UBound(vName)
'        k = Ln - Len(vName(i))
'        vName(i) = vName(i) & Space(k * 2)
'        M = Len(vName(i))
'    Next i

    With Cht
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked

        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Target.Value
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "OCF Percentiles"
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 50
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .Name = vName(i)    '<~~ Collection name
                .Values = Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(3).Offset(0, i)
                .XValues = Array("A", "D", "I")
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vColor(i)
                If i = 0 Then
                    .Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.5 '<~~~~~ Transparency was adjusted
                End If
            End With
        Next i
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Srs
            .Name = vName(3)    '<~~ Collection name
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Values = Target.Offset(0, 4).Resize(1, 3)
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = vColor(3) 'vbBlack
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]